# Filling Window with One Column

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app

I am having an issue which seems trivial but is giving me a headache. Working on a UWP app, I am designing a account screen. 
[Currently it looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qE8F.png)
Obviously I want this to be centered and have the background fill the window, regardless of the window size. Below is my current code

```
  <Grid Background="#FFECF0F1" x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="FirstColumn" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SecondColumn" Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ThirdColumn" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
        <RelativePanel Grid.Column="1" x:Name="UserInfoPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="25" >
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="accountImage" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <TextBlock x:Name="displayUserName"  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" Text="User Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Button x:Name="signOutButton"  Click="signOutButton_Click" Content="Sign Out" Margin="0,0,10,10" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="131"/>
        </RelativePanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock  x:Name="signInText" Text="Not Currently Signed In " FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
            <Button x:Name="signInButton" Content="Sign In" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="signInButton_Click" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="66"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="BioPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0"  Width="500" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock x:Name="preferedCar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Preferred Car:"  Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="dropDownCar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
            <TextBlock x:Name="bestScore" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Best Score: 6.9" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="drivingTime" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Time Driving with FuelE.co: 32 Hours" Margin="0,20,0,0"  />
            <TextBox x:Name="bio" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your Bio" Height="236" Margin="0,20,0,0"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The main idea here is that I am setting the StackPanels in column 1, which should use as much space as needed, and the other two columns should then just fill the rest of the space, but this is not the case.

EDIT:
See the updated picture above. I guess it must be the fact that I am using a split pane. The account screen is being displayed in a frame in the split panel. For example this is the code for it in main.xaml:

```
            <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="MyFrame" Background="#FFECF0F1"></Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
```

and then in c#:

```
MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Account));
```

Perhaps there is something I must do with the frame to get it to fill the screen?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have shown, you don't need all those rows and columns.

Try something like this:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray">
        <TextBlock Text="illegitimi non carborundum" Margin="0,10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="illegitimi non carborundum" Margin="0,10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="illegitimi non carborundum" Margin="0,10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Which gives:

[image]

And your code *might* look like this:

```
<Grid Background="#FFECF0F1" x:Name="RootGrid">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <RelativePanel Grid.Column="1" x:Name="UserInfoPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="25" >
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="accountImage" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <TextBlock x:Name="displayUserName"  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" Text="User Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Button x:Name="signOutButton"  Click="signOutButton_Click" Content="Sign Out" Margin="0,0,10,10" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="131"/>
        </RelativePanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock  x:Name="signInText" Text="Not Currently Signed In " FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
            <Button x:Name="signInButton" Content="Sign In" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="signInButton_Click" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="66"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel x:Name="BioPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0"  Width="500" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock x:Name="preferedCar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Preferred Car:"  Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="dropDownCar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
            <TextBlock x:Name="bestScore" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Best Score: 6.9" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="drivingTime" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Time Driving with FuelE.co: 32 Hours" Margin="0,20,0,0"  />
            <TextBox x:Name="bio" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Your Bio" Height="236" Margin="0,20,0,0"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Edit to aid with debugging:

I turned all your panels on, and they all align as I expected.

[image]

If this does not work for you, then you either are not showing all your code, or you need to *debug* and turn things on/off, go back to a simple design that works and build up from there, etc.

Comment: I tried this but it yielded the same result. I have used this same style working on other pages but it does not on this one, no idea why it is not stretching.

Comment: I included more comment in the question above, perhaps the frame is the issue

Comment: Don't guess.  Debug.  Change your Account page to just a simple grid or stack panel with a background color to test and see if that works as you expect.  Add your real content one by one and see if/when it breaks.